# Fastest way to compare two integer arrays for value comparison

Tags: c#, arrays, performance

I know that array comparison questions have been asked multiple times but I am curious to know if there is a better method than the ones I have tried so far.

The requirement is to compare two integer arrays of same length to check if one of them has values which are always greater than or equal to the ones in the second one when mapped one to one. So, if you were to sort the arrays (which I did for comparing them), the values at the same indices in the first array should always be greater than or equal to the ones at the same indices in the second one.

I tried the check in two ways so far:

1. Sort the arrays. Run a for loop and return a false value if any of the values in the second array turns out to be greater than the corresponding value in the first array:

```
    Array.Sort(Array1);
    Array.Sort(Array2);
    //
    for (int i = 0; i < Array1.length; i++)
    {
        if (Array2[i] > Array1[i])
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
```

2. In the alternate method, I tried to be cute and used the chaining of FindIndex and IndexOf methods to get the solution in one go. I think it's actually less efficient since, as far as I can tell and please correct me if I am wrong, it is traversing the array twice instead of once as is the case in the previous method:

```
    Array.Sort(Array1);
    Array.Sort(Array2);
    //
    return Array.FindIndex(Array2, i => i > Array1[Array.IndexOf(Array2, i)]) >= 0 
      ? false 
      : true;
```

I think the first method works better but is there a faster/better way to achieve the same result? The number of elements can range from 10 to 10000.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need a faster or better way than the first? It should be fast enough. You may use parallel threads to compare the indexes but seems overcomplicated and may not event be faster for just 10000 items.

Comment: Why not use linq with `return Array1.SequenceEqual(Array2)`

Comment: @mm8 I am actually fine with using the first method and, like you correctly pointed out, it's true that I may not see any performance improvement for the sample size I have. I am just curious if there is a better way to handle this case in general since my solution felt very basic. It's one of those things where you do something and then think back to the time when you saw a solution shared online which accomplished something in a much efficient way than what you would have tried, so I thought maybe there is a better way to handle this case as well, if only just for the learning experience.

Comment: @ThomasK The values don't have to be equal in both the arrays, so SequenceEqual wouldn't work in this case.

Comment: Are you sure your implementation satisfies the requirements you provided? For me, `which are always greater` implies comparing of all elements in the arrays not only first unequal pair. How for example, the arrays [1, 5, 12] and [2, 3, 8] should be compared ?

Comment: @DmytroMukalov The values in the first array should be greater than or equal to the values in the second array when mapped one to one. So, if you can find a combination where every single value in the first array is mapped to a single value in the second array and all of them turn out to be greater than or equal to their counterparts then the arrays satisfy the condition, otherwise not. In your example, the arrays will fail the test since no such mapping exists (1 being lower than the lowest value in the second array). My apologies if this was clear in the problem description.